# Replace \" from a string

Tags: c#, xml, regex, string, replace

I have a long string (500,000+ characters) that contains an RSS feed in XML format. I'm trimming some parts of the XML to clean up the information before parsing it. However, when I call this code:

```
string rssData = string.Empty;
//Get RSS data here
rssData = rssData.Replace("\\\"", string.Empty);
```

The backslash characters are not removed. Is there a limitation to doing replacements of a character when the string is that long?

Here's an example snippet of the string being replaced. I'm removing the backslashes to properly parse the quotation marks:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><rss version=\"2.0\" xmlns:atom=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\" xmlns:cc=\"http://web.resource.org/cc/\"......
```

EDIT: It turns out that the reason I'm getting replacement errors is because all backslashes are succeeded by a quotation mark, which must be causing some sort of error in the string replacement.

The updated question: **How do I remove the backslash from the sequence \" using string.Replace?**

Comment: In your environment, does replacing the backslash on the smaller string work?

Comment: @PatrickQuirk Yes it does. However, now I'm thinking that it could have something to do with the fact that the backslashes are followed by quotation marks? Maybe the string is being read incorrectly because of that.

Comment: How did you check that it doesn't work? In the debugger, the " sign is prepended by a backslash, but that doesn't exist in the string, it's just to show the string the way you have to enter it in source code. Normally RSS data (or XML in general) does not contain backslashes in front of the quotes.

Comment: @okrumnow when I use the XDocument.Parse method, it throws an error, and my string has \" instead of just ". I tried replacing just " and it worked, but if I do just \ it doesn't change. I used the HtmlDecode methods of WebUtility and HttpUtility, however, which may be causing the problem.

Comment: What's the error you got?

Comment: @okrumnow There is no error, the string just remains the same. The backslashes are not removed.

Comment: @miguelarcilla In your last comment, you mentioned an error that was thrown by XDocument.Parse

Comment: Your regex works fine so the problem must be with the target string (rssData). It must not be in the format you're expecting.

Comment: @okrumnow & Keith You guys are right. I removed the HtmlDecodes and it's parsing properly now :) thanks, it really was just my input that got messed up.

Comment: can you write the complete xml string or structured one with these slashes??